# dart function to copy text to clipboard with MIME type

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dart, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy text to the OS clipboard in my dart web app with the push of a button, and I'm not finding a clean way of doing so.

My current solution is to create a textArea element, add the text I'm intending to copy to the element, calling `document.execCommand("copy")` on said element, then deleting the textArea element.  This works in the browsers I am intending to support; however, I also need to set the MIME type for this copied text, which does not appear to be possible with my current implementation.

So, my question for you all is:  using my current solution, can I also set the MIME type for the text being copied?  OR is there a better approach I could take using a different dart api?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript (even dart converted to javascript) cannot get to the OS clipboard.  Only Flash seems to have that ability.